# Rails + Cloudfront - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

So I've configured my Ruby on Rails app to use CloudFront as a CDN. JavaScript, CSS & image assets seem to be serving correctly via CloudFront but fonts are failing with a CORS issue -

```
Access to Font at 'https://abcdefghikl.cloudfront.net/assets/fonts/din-regularalternate-webfont-79090091223f0c54d7042ef125ad4f26.ttf' from origin 'https://myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

I have whitelisted the following headers on AWS CloudFront as well. Btw, the fonts are being served from my Rails server (not from S3).

[image]

Comment: Have you configure CloudFront to whitelist the CORS request headers to the origin server?  Where are these fonts? On your server, or on S3, or elsewhere?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot answered your questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example Rails 5.2 app that serves a custom font through CloudFront. It runs on Heroku with the [Edge addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge) but applies to any Rails / CloudFront setup.

https://github.com/nzoschke/edgecors

First you need to configure CloudFront to forward the browser `Origin` header.

Next use the `rack-cors` gem and add a configuration to your Rails `config/application.rb`:

```
module EdgeCors
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins %w[
          http://edgecors.herokuapp.com
          https://edgecors.herokuapp.com
        ]
        resource '/assets/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Change the origin whitelist to your website URL.

Now requests from `https://edgecors.herokuapp.com` to a font at `https://abcdefghikl.cloudfront.net/assets/fonts/din-regularalternate-webfont-79090091223f0c54d7042ef125ad4f26.ttf` will be sent back to the origin Rails app.

The middleware introspects the `Origin` header and adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://edgecors.herokuapp.com` header to the response if it is in the whitelist.

The browser will then happily load the font. And CloudFront will cache.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - you can't. This requires a change at the server-side - nothing you can do in your client (browser) code. CORS only applies to AJAX requests (using fetch under the covers) and fonts.

But if the server side is under your control, check whether you are explicitly adding the CORS response headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin etc.) in your response from your Rails server.

If not, you'll need to actually ADD them to the response (either at the Rails server or in the CDN itself). Whitelisting them simply allows them through (and may affect caching), but they need to be explicitly added to the response

---

Fun fact: CORS was developed SPECIFICALLY to stop people from accessing/downloading fonts from 'font factories'...

Comment: Given that OP states that he has *"configured my Ruby on Rails app to use CloudFront as a CDN"* ...I'm reasonably sure he's trying to access **his own content** via CloudFront.  Thus he is in fact hosting it himself and has control of the server side.

Comment: Michael is right. Your answer does not help me and I know CORS can't be bypassed only with the client in hand. That aside the history trivia is cool :)

Comment: OK, well are you explicitly adding the CORS response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` etc.) in your response from your Rails server? If not, you'll need to actually ADD them to the response (either at the Rails server or in the CDN itself). Whitelisting them simply allows them through (and may affect caching), but they need to be explicitly added to the response.

Comment: Thank YOU @SteveRobinson :)